# How to redirect to another page and open popup with specific parameters?

Tags: angularjs

I have button:

```
<input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="btn-search" ng-click="SearchPin(0,pin);ShowDetails(pin);">
```

I want when user click on search button to redirect it on another page but to remember parameters so that i can show details on that redirected page... is that possible?

Comment: use $location.path('/your/path').search( { 'param_name_1': 'param_value_1', 'param_name_2': 'param_value_2' } ) and after on new screen load use $routeParams.param_name_1 and $routeParams.param_name_2 to get any params you need

Comment: im not sure that i understand u...can u post an example ?

Comment: because when it redirect me on another page i lose parameters

Comment: my friend! you can't drive a car if you haven't passed the driving test. same with angular, question you are asking is so primitive, that you probably can do that after watching some simple video lessons about Angular basics. Open youtube or search 'Angular basics torrent', spend 2 hours in the morning and 2 hours in the evening watching lessons, after a week you can answer that question by yourself. no personal benefit for you if someone give you answer. trust me!